# How to handle Enter keydown event in assembly language x86?

Tags: events, assembly, x86, interruptions

I am new to assembly programming and I have an assembly (x86) codes which accepts input from the user. The console will continuously (looped) ask the user to input another character until such "enter" key is pressed. When "enter" key is pressed, the console will automatically stops from asking for more inputs.

How could I possibly do that? Is it something to do with interruptions?
Thanks for the advice...

Comment: Simple google search returned several results.
One is
    http://www.softwareforeducation.com/sms32v50/sms32v50_manual/150-05keyb-in.htm

and the better one is:

   http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/x86_asm/300660/300676/re-keyboard-input/

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Probably a software interrupt is what you need (`int` instruction). See the links @icbytes provided. If you do a Google search on "x86 keyboard input" you'll get several very good hits.

Answer (score 0):

When running without an operating system or under MS-DOS you have two possibilities:

The first one:

- Access the keyboard (I/O ports) directly (using IN and OUT instructions)
- You'll have to catch or disable the keyboard interrupt also because otherwise the BIOS will "steal" keyboard requests

The second one:

- Access the keyboard using the BIOS interrupt "INT 0x16"

When you are using a modern operating system (Windows, Linux, ...) you cannot directly access the keyboard; you'll have to call operating system API functions - the same ones that you would call when programming in C:

```
// C example:
getchar();
```

And:

```
# Assembler example (Windows: _getchar, Linux: getchar):
call _getchar
```

Answer (score -1):

In 8086, when you input something, it will be stored in 'AL' part of the register. So, you can simply compare 'AL' with '0DH' (Here, 0D is the hexadecimal representation of ENTER key).

To compare 'AL' with '0DH', you can simply write "CMP AL,0DH".

Comment: This doesn't answer *how to input something*. It's correct, but almost entirely useless.